# Url.RouteUrl not gettting an API route in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I created a MVC 5 site using its template and added the following API controller:

```
namespace MvcSite.Controllers {

  public class TestController : ApiController {

    [Route("test/send"), HttpGet]
    public String Send() {    
      return "SENT";
    }

  } // TestController
} // MvcSite.Controllers
```

When I access "/test/send" I get the string "SENT" back as expected ...

In a Razor view or in a Controller I need to get the URL of the send action so I tried:

```
var url = Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "Test", action = "Send", HttpRoute = true });
```

But url is null ... I have no idea why ...

The API route is working fine so it is in the Route Table ...

What am I missing?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Configure a named route and use the [HttpRouteUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.httprouteurl.aspx) method to get the URL.

```
[Route("test/send", Name = "Send"), HttpGet]
public String Send() {    
  return "SENT";
}
```

Get the URL like this:

```
var url = Url.HttpRouteUrl("Send", new {});
```

Comment: This works, but is there a way to not have to specify the empty object in instances where I don't need to specify any route parameters.